# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android' when run flutter project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, genymotion

I have this error when I run flutter project for the first time

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
               > Remote host closed connection during handshake

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How can I fix it ?
Note that I am running a project on `genymotion`

Comment: Do you have the google() repo in your project's level build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

either you internet not working properly or add google() in gradle..

something like this

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

can you add the build build.gradle file so that we can see what is going wrong